# ssh-add prompting for PEM pass phrase for unknown reason

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh, git

So some background: I have a collection of systems I use to access a server, which authenticate with a fingerprint key over ssh. On my other systems (android, windows 10, centos 7) I have no issues using a script to add the keys to the ssh keychain when they're needed.

However, on one windows 10 instance, the key asks for a PEM passphrase and fails with `<private key location> is not a key file.` before prompting for a passphrase. Below are the two prompts to illustrate what I'm talking about:

`Enter PEM pass phrase:`

`Enter passphrase for <private key location>:`

Now, the key is the same, and does work as expected once the first key input fails and the second succeeds, but why is it even prompting for the PEM passphrase when my other systems don't bother? And how can I get rid of that prompt?

Other details that may be relevant:

- error occurs using git bash for windows (installed pre-WSL), but works on another machine's implementation (same git version installed).
- windows versions are the same across implementations

Comment: Are you sure you're actually running the legit ssh-add tool? This sounds _very much_ like a script that steals your private key. What processes show up in e.g. ProcExp while the 1st prompt is waiting? What messages show up if you enter an incorrect passphrase at the 1st prompt?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I can verify that the ssh-add tool is legitimate (used the exact same install file across multiple instances, checksums OK). The bash script I use is one I coded myself that uses the tool, and the prompt appears correctly in other instances. It just says that my key isn't a key and moves on to the correct prompt. When I have time I'll just try a redeploy/reinstall - need to do it anyways for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much frustration I figured out that there was nothing actually wrong with the key file, script, or utilities.

The problem was a missing public key file that the ssh-keygen utility apparently required. The specific code segment causing the problem was `ssh-keygen -lf /path/to/key/file`.

After replacing the missing public key, it no longer asks for a PEM pass phrase, and instead just prompts for the key's passphrase as expected.